# How to disable the long press gesture of a QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have a `UIView` as the main view and add a `QLPreviewController` as the subview over that while previewing the document. I want to restrict the long press gesture so that no one can copy contents from the document. I have tried the following code:

**Code Snippet :**

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil]; 

longPress.allowableMovement=100; 

longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.3; 
longPress.delegate=self; 
longPress.delaysTouchesBegan=YES;
longPress.delaysTouchesEnded=YES;

longPress.cancelsTouchesInView=YES; 
[previewController.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress]; 
[self.view addSubview:previewController.view];
```

But no success. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong and what could be done to disable the long press gesture ?

I have tried this as well :

```
NSArray *arr = previewController.view.gestureRecognizers;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {

     if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {

         [previewController.view removeGestureRecognizer:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
NSArray *arr = qlPreviewController.gestureRecognizers;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {

    if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {

        [qlPreviewController removeGestureRecognizer:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

`qlPreviewController` is the object of `QLPreviewController`'s view on wich `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is there!

`qlPreviewController` is `view` not `viewcontroller` make sure that!

**Update :**

for example;

```
  QLPreviewController *vc;  

  UIView *qlPreviewController = vc.view;
```

**Update 2:**

you can use this `delegate method` to disable gesture recognizer!

```
  - (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{

    return NO;


 }
```

Comment: Let me try .. And am sure it isn't a view controller

Comment: Can u tell me what do u mean by qlPreviewController is the object of QLPreviewController's view ?

Comment: that means the main view of `QLPreviewController` because we adds gesture recognizer on `view` not on viewcontroller!! got it?

Comment: and I get an error "No Visible @interface for 'QLPreviewController' declares the selector for 'removeGestureRecognizer' "

Comment: you need to remove gesture recognizer from `previewController.view`. and you got error because you doing same mistake of which i was afraid. You are trying to get array of recognizer from viewcontroller rather than view!!!

Comment: i have update your question now try this one. you was removing gesture recognizer from `previewController` actually you need to remove from `previewController.view`

Comment: Understood.. I ll try now and get back to u''

Comment: you need to remove long press gesture from `QLPreviewController`'s view!! If that's not work then you can implement delegate method `shouldReceiveTouch` to disable it!

Comment: I am adding a long press gesture to the qlpreviewcontroller's view with csncelsTouchInView set to NO.. Why SHould I remove it ?